# __* in Mysql regular expression

Tags: mysql, sql

I am refering one open source code. There I can found an sql with this kind of a filter.

```
select sometext from table1,table2 where table1.sometext LIKE
CONCAT('% ',table2.test_keyword,' %') AND table2.test_keyword NOT
REGEXP '__*';
```

What is that __* in this sql?

Comment: Did you consult your regular expressions book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__*` matches one `_` followed by zero or more `_`s.

```
__*
^^^
||\__ (zero or more)     ^
|\___ underscore         |
\____ underscore, then   |
```

---

`_+` would have done the same job.

```
_+
^^
|\__ (one or more)       ^
\___ underscore          |
```

Comment: One `_` followed by **zero** or more `_`.

Comment: @KennyTM: That's what I wrote! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's simply one or more underscore characters.

The pattern is best read as:

- `'_'`, exactly one underscore,
- `'_*'`, followed by zero or more underscores.

Keep in mind that, without a start marker, that will match the pattern at *any* location in the string, so it basically means any string with an underscore in it (or, more accurately, since you're using `NOT`, a string *without* an underscore).

It's also needlessly complex, since you could achieve the same effect with `AND table2.test_keyword NOT REGEXP '_'`.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) for the latest MySQL documentation on regexes (5.6 at the time of this answer).